# Testing Django Wizard Views

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-testing, django-formwizard, django-formtools

I'm writing tests for my wizard using this excellent example from [PyDoc.net](http://pydoc.net/django-formwizard/1.0/formwizard.tests.wizardtests.tests/).

One of the methods in my TestCase is not returning the correct step in the wizard:

```
class WizardTests(TestCase):
    wizard_step_data = (
        {
            'step2-address': '123 Anywhere Ln.'
            'wizard_wizard-current_step': 'step2'
        },
    )

    def test_form_post_success(self):
        response = self.client.post('/wizard/new/step2', self.wizard_step_data[0])
        wizard = response.context['wizard']
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(wizard['steps'].current, 'step2')
```

When I run this, I get back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/app/wizard/tests.py", line 71, in test_form_post_success
    self.assertEqual(wizard['steps'].current, 'step2')
AssertionError: 'step1' != 'step2'
```

I am using a NamedUrlSessionWizardView, which is why my URL on the `self.client.post` is `/wizard/new/step2`, as opposed to just `/wizard/` like the example above.  Otherwise, I receive 404's, or 301's for `/wizard/new`.

Do you have any ideas about what could be causing this?